# How to use OpenBlas Lapacke together with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package, lapacke

I have some running c++ code using the `Lapacke` version that comes with `OpenBlas`. I would like to include this code into an R package and transfer data between that function and R using the `Rcpp` package. But somehow the two seem not to like each other. As soon as I have `#include <lapacke.h>` and  `#include <Rcpp.h>` in one source file it isn't compiling anymore. Both separately work fine. There is a whole bunch off error messages which as far as I can tell say that `Rcpp` is broken (e.g `/home/Alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/traits/traits.h:32:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__extension__’)`.

I have no idea why this happens. Is there a way to use both at the same time?
Or should I do something completely different?

Here is a minimal example that gives me the error:

1. I created a package using

   ```
   Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("LT", example_code = FALSE)
   ```
2. I added a `.cpp` file to `/src` containing

   ```
   #include <lapacke.h>
   #include <Rcpp.h>

   int test_LAPACK(){
     return(1);
   }
   ```
3. I added a Makvars file to `/src` containing

   ```
   PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I/opt/OpenBLAS/include
   PKG_LIBS =  -L/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -lopenblas -lpthread -lgfortran
   CXX_STD = CXX11
   ```
4. Compile and install

   ```
   Rcpp::compileAttributes("LT")
   devtools::install("LT")
   ```

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel At least for my simple example changing the order of the includes seem to work. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: That is _very often_ the case.  Large projects tend to define things, other projects may get "hit" by that.  Experience teaches you to put certain things first or last.  Worst case you have conflicting needs...

Comment: But yes, added that comment as an edit to the answer--the key really is the link order here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually works on my system following a standard `sudo apt install liblapacke-dev` *provided I also change the include order*.

Witness:

#### Source

```
rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$ cat src/lt.cpp 
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

int test_LAPACK(){
          return(1);
}
rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$ ls src/      ## no Makevars needed
lt.cpp
rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$
```

#### Build

```
rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$ build.r 
* checking for file ‘./DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘LT’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to process help pages
* saving partial Rd database
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
Removed empty directory ‘LT/R’
* building ‘LT_1.0.tar.gz’

rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$
```

#### Install

```
rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$ install.r LT_1.0.tar.gz 
* installing *source* package ‘LT’ ...
** libs
ccache g++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe   -march=native -c lt.cpp -o lt.o
ccache g++ -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o LT.so lt.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/LT/libs
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (LT)
rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$
```

#### Run

(After I added a line `// [[Rcpp::export]]`, ran `compileAtttributes()` and rebuilt and installed.)

```
rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$ r -lLT -p -e'test_LAPACK()'
[1] 1
rob:/tmp/lapacke/LT$
```

#### Summary

Check your compiler. There is no fundamental reason this should not work, and it works here (Ubuntu 18.04).